# CMSIS USB firmware for stm32f401. Fails to send device descriptor with EOVERFLOW (-75) error

Tags: embedded, usb, stm32, stm32f4, usb-otg

I am trying to get USB device code working on my stm32f401 microcontroller. So far, I'm able to read the packets from the host, send the first device request, receive and apply the assigned address. After that, the host requests for the device descriptor again, and my device doesn't response to that for some reason. I've been fighting this issue for weeks now, seems like I need help with it.

In my code, after initializing the peripherals, I set up my endpoint 0 and set its Tx FIFO size to 16. When the device receives a packet, it reads the packet status and reads the packet content in function setup_packet_handler(). This function prints the content word by word:

```
uint32_t data = *fifo;
printf("Rx from FIFO: 0x%08x\n", data);


void rxflvl_handler() {
    uint32_t packet_status = USB_OTG_FS->GRXSTSP;

    uint8_t endpoint_number = (packet_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_EPNUM_Msk) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_EPNUM_Pos;
    uint16_t bcnt = (packet_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT_Msk) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_BCNT_Pos;
    uint16_t pktsts = (packet_status & USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS_Msk) >> USB_OTG_GRXSTSP_PKTSTS_Pos;

    printf("Received packet of status 0x%02x\n", pktsts);
    switch (pktsts) {
    case 0x06: // SETUP packet (includes data)
        setup_packet_handler(endpoint_number, bcnt);
        break;
    case 0x02: // OUT packet (includes data)
        break;
    case 0x04: // SETUP stage has completed
    case 0x03: // OUT transfer has completed
        // Re-enable the endpoint
        OUT_ENDPOINT(endpoint_number)->DOEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DOEPCTL_CNAK;
        OUT_ENDPOINT(endpoint_number)->DOEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DOEPCTL_EPENA;
        break;
    }
}
```

My main() function watches the current number of packets to send and free space of the Tx FIFO for endpoint 0:

```
int main(void)
{
  /* Pins initialization */
  /* USB initialization */
  
  in_packets = (in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ & USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Msk) >> USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos;
  fifo_space = in_endpoint->DTXFSTS & USB_OTG_DTXFSTS_INEPTFSAV_Msk;
  printf("FIFO free space: %i\n", fifo_space);
  while (1)
  {
    // Checking for USB interrupts
    usb_poll();

    // Notify if packets number changed
    uint32_t npkts = (in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ & USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Msk) >> USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos;
    if (npkts != in_packets) {
      printf("Packets number update: %i\n", npkts);
      in_packets = npkts;
    }

    // Notify if FIFO space changed
    uint16_t new_space = in_endpoint->DTXFSTS & USB_OTG_DTXFSTS_INEPTFSAV_Msk;
    if (new_space != fifo_space) {
      fifo_space = new_space;
      printf("FIFO free space: %i\n", new_space);
    }
  }
}
```

Now the broken part, the code which sends the device descriptor. The function handle_descriptor_request() is called when the device descriptor request is received.
The function sets the size to transmit to 18; packet count to 3 (endpoint 0 max packet size is configured to 8); enables the endpoint and fills the FIFO. After that, prints the FIFO free space, to ensure it has decreased.

```
void handle_descriptor_request(void) {
  printf("Received descriptor request\n");
  uint32_t* fifo  = (USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE + USB_OTG_FIFO_BASE +
          0 * 0x1000);
  USB_OTG_INEndpointTypeDef* in_endpoint = (USB_OTG_INEndpointTypeDef*)(
                  USB_OTG_FS_PERIPH_BASE +
                  USB_OTG_IN_ENDPOINT_BASE +
                  0
                  );

  // flush_txfifo(0);
  // in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ = 0;
  // in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_SNAK;
  // in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_EPDIS;
  
  printf("Manual PKTCNT to 3\n");
  // Set Tx size to 18
  in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ &= ~USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_XFRSIZ_Msk;
  in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ &= ~USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Msk;
  in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ |= 18 << USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_XFRSIZ_Pos;
  // Send 3 packets (8 bytes max for each)
  in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ |= 3 << USB_OTG_DIEPTSIZ_PKTCNT_Pos;
  
  // Enable transmission
  in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_CNAK;
  in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_EPENA;

  // Write a valid device descriptor to the Tx FIFO
  *fifo = 0x02000112;
  *fifo = 0x08000000;

  *fifo = 0x13aa6666;
  *fifo = 0x00000000;
  *fifo = 0x0000012c;

  fifo_space = in_endpoint->DTXFSTS & USB_OTG_DTXFSTS_INEPTFSAV_Msk;
  printf("FIFO free space: %i\n", fifo_space);
}
```

Below is the log I'm getting from the device. I see that the first device request is transmitted successfully, the FIFO size drops from 16 to 11, than back to 16. Number of packets to send decreases from 3 to 2 (although it should decrease to 0, right?). I also see this descriptor with Wireshark. Then the device address is received and answered by a ZLP packet; then something goes wrong. My FIFO space keeps decreasing with every descriptor request, the packets doesn't seem to leave the device.

```
USB reset received
FIFO free space: 16
INEPNE Endpoint interrupt
TXFE Endpoint interrupt

// First descriptor request. Sent successfully

Received packet of status 0x06

// Device descriptor request in binary form
Rx from FIFO: 0x01000680
Rx from FIFO: 0x00400000

// Output from handle_descriptor_request()
Received descriptor request
Manual PKTCNT to 3
FIFO free space: 11

// Output from main()
Packets number update: 2
FIFO free space: 16

// Output from rxflvl_handler()
Received packet of status 0x04
Received packet of status 0x02
Received packet of status 0x03
INEPNE Endpoint interrupt
TXFE Endpoint interrupt

// Received address

Received packet of status 0x06

// Set address request in binary form
Rx from FIFO: 0x001d0500
Rx from FIFO: 0x00000000
Received address: 29
Writing zero-length packet
Manual PKTCNT to 1
Packets number update: 1
Received packet of status 0x04
Packets number update: 0
TXFRC Endpoint interrupt
TXFE Endpoint interrupt

// Another device descriptor request

Received packet of status 0x06
Rx from FIFO: 0x01000680
Rx from FIFO: 0x00120000
Received descriptor request
Manual PKTCNT to 3
FIFO free space: 11
Packets number update: 3
Received packet of status 0x04

// Looks unsuccessful. Try again...

Received packet of status 0x06
Rx from FIFO: 0x01000680
Rx from FIFO: 0x00120000
Received descriptor request
Manual PKTCNT to 3
FIFO free space: 6

// And so on. The FIFO free space decreases to 0
```

Here are the Wireshark views of the first and second descriptor responses. The second one fails with EOVERFLOW (-75). Sometimes I see -71 error when run 'dmesg' on my host. Can't figure out what is the reason for that.
[image: Wireshark view of the successful package]
[image: Wireshark view of the unsuccessful package]

If I will be flushing the 0th FIFO before the descriptor transmission, i.e. uncomment the

```
flush_txfifo(0);
```

Thing doesn't change a lot: the FIFO free space stops decreasing below 11, but the packets doesn't seem to be sent.
If I recover the endpoint before the descriptor tranmission, uncommenting the

```
in_endpoint->DIEPTSIZ = 0;
in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_SNAK;
in_endpoint->DIEPCTL |= USB_OTG_DIEPCTL_EPDIS;
```

then starting at the second try, the device seems to strart sending something, but still something wrong. The FIFO size increases to 15 words instead of 16

```
// ...

Rx from FIFO: 0x01000680
Rx from FIFO: 0x00120000
Received descriptor request
Manual PKTCNT to 3
FIFO free space: 11
FIFO free space: 15
Received packet of status 0x04
Received packet of status 0x02
Received packet of status 0x03
```

Also I can't understand why the number of packets drops from 3 to 2 for the successful transmission. I can see in Wireshark whole descriptor (18 bytes) and the endpoint size is configured to 8.
Could you point me to things I may need to check?

Comment: Very difficult to say what's not working. Possible problems: (1) The descriptor request contains a length. The response must not exceeded it even if it is too short for the entire descriptor. The host will requery with a longer length. (2) `printf()` is usually a bad idea as it introduces delays that violate USB timing.

Comment: @Codo, The broken request asks for 0x0012 bytes, which is 18 in decimal - the device sends the packet of this exact size. 
Tried to run without the printf()s - it still doesn't work.
Thank you for the tips, if something else comes to your mind - I'd be happy to hear that!